# Create new session using _IECreate()

Tags: session, internet-explorer, autoit

I have two AutoIt scripts. Both contain `Global $oIE = _IECreate($myUrl, 1)`. They create two IE windows for the same URL.

In IE, when selecting "new session" from "file" menu, each window gets its own session. But using two different script files at the same time, both windows login to the same account. How can I open every IE window with a new session?

Answer (score 1):

Sessions relate to each unique iexplore.exe process. Start new instance of iexplore.exe per required session (untested, no error checking) :

```
#include <IE.au3>

Global Const $g_sUrl = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
Global       $g_aIE[2]

For $i1 = 0 To UBound($g_aIE, 1) -1    
    _IECreateSession($g_aIE[$i1], $g_sUrl)    
Next

Func _IECreateSession(ByRef $oIE, Const $sUrl)
    Local Const $iPID = ShellExecute('iexplore.exe', '-nosessionmerging about:blank')
    Local       $aWnd

    WinWait('Blank Page')       
    $aWnd = _WinAPI_EnumProcessWindows($iPID, True)
    $oIE  = _IEAttach($aWnd[1][1], 'hwnd')    
    _IELoadWait($oIE)
    _IENavigate($oIE, $sUrl)

    Return $iPID    
EndFunc
```

Comment: Thanks it solved the problem but after i added

RegWrite('HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main','SessionMerging','REG_DWORD','00000000')

ShellExecute ("iexplore.exe", " -nosessionmerging about:blank")

Comment: @MouadElBhiri Closing explorer's windows does not suffice; sessions relate to each unique `iexplore.exe` _process_. That registry setting isolates sessions to individual _tabs_ (which _may_ fit your purpose just fine). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826025(v=vs.85).aspx